# Unable to start Apache2 after attempt to switch php version

Tags: apache2, php, reboot

After trying to switch php versions on my local Apache2 installation I have been unable to restart Apache at all.
When calling up `systemctl status apache2.service` I see the following message:

```
Oct 07 11:02:33 philipp-ubuntu-Inspiron-3670 apachectl[5221]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load: Cannot load>
```

And that the 'start' failed.

Line 146 of the conf file is:

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
```

Line 3 of php7.4.load is:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated as I can no longer access any of my local web applications rn.

Thanks!

Comment: A few questions for you: Have you confirmed that `libphp7.4.so` exists? Which PHP versions are you working with? How did you make the change? Apache is sometimes very particular about the order a change must follow in order to work 

Comment: Hi there, thanks for getting back to me, it's much appreciated. You're right, even though php7.4 was listed as a possible option after querying the system for the alternatives and I got no error message when I enabled it with 'a2enmod php7.4', the module was not actually installed.

I downloaded and installed php 7.4 and was then able to reboot Apache properly and with the different php versions if needed. 

Many thanks again!